# Proving Vector Identities: a · b = 0 and x + (x · b)a = b

Tags: vectors

If $\vec{a} ·\vec{b} = 0$ and $\vec{x} + (\vec{x} · \vec{b})\vec{a} = \vec{b}$, ﬁnd the vector $\vec{x}$.

By transposing I have got $(\vec{b} - \vec{x})· \vec{b} = 0$.

Apparently the answer is : $\vec{x}= \vec{b}-(|b|^2)\vec{a}$

Comment: What do you mean by _transposing_?

Comment: a=(b-x)/(x⋅b) and by taking dot product of b throughout you get (b−x)⋅b=0

Answer (score 2):

$$\vec{x}+(\vec{x}\cdot \vec{b})\vec{a}=\vec{b}$$
Taking dot-product with $b$ throughout,
$$\vec{x}\cdot \vec{b} + (\vec{x}\cdot \vec{b})(\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b})=|\vec{b}|^2$$
We know that $\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}=0$. Hence
$$\vec{x}\cdot \vec{b} = |\vec{b}|^2$$
Substituting back in the first equation,
$$\vec{x}+(|\vec{b}|^2)\vec{a}=\vec{b}$$

What you got by transposing was correct. If you expand that, you get
$$|b|^2-x\cdot b=0$$